# HTML - How do css/javascript files get loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Good day!

I have stumbled on a problem, and I can't seem to wrap my mind around it.

Let's say I am loading a page with this url `http://example.com/home`. Then I load the html into my `index.php` and it displays it with all the css and js attached. Works like a charm and how I want it to work.

The problem comes in here, if I request this url `http://example.com/home/test`. It still load the same html, that is how I made it work. But now, it doesn't load the `css` and `js` files anymore that are used for the design. They don't have their old content anymore in them, but the content of the page itself. To clearify:

**My css at first** and how it's loaded at the first URL example.

```
body{ margin: 0; background:rgb(0,0,1);}
```

**2nd url css result**

```
<html> My html I loaded, but not the css anymore </html>
```

**EDIT**:

The `html` file I load is the same over and over again, it doesn't listen to the `url` to load a file, it just `require_once` the same html file. The path's to the js and css are `static`.

**My question**: How do `css` and `js` files get loaded? How can you remove the effect of the `/test` in loading the extra files.

I hope I explained it well enough, if not, please say so and I will try to make it more clear.

Comment: is the js, and css in the same folder as `test.html`? if not maybe you are having problem with relative paths.

Comment: home/test  is new directory where  you have another index.php ?   .. please  show the code  .. (where you load css  and js)

Comment: what code you have used to load css and js files in home/test.If you are using an IDE like netbeans you can ctrl+click to see if the path to css and js are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is load a css or json file by specifying the root. For example:
Instead of using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
```

You should use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/mystyle.css">
```

Else it will in your case search for a CSS file that is called http://example.com/home/somecss.css instead of http://example.com/somecss.css

Comment: Yes, that solved my problem. I will accept it as the answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use absolute paths, for example:

`<link rel='stylesheet' href='/css/style.css' type='text/css' media='all' />`

Answer (score 0):

You have to include js and css file on that page.

say if you have one js file called my.js and one css file called style.css one the home directory/folder and you want to display it from another directory.Then, you have to include it on the page with right path.

for example:
home/style.css 
home/my.js

home/ is you default folder where js and css my is located. Now you want to show these file from here:
home/test/

then on the index page (which is on the test/ directory) you have to write

```
for css: 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css" />

for js:
<script src="../my.js"></script>
```

on the `<head>` tag of the page.

Comment: This is not what I was looking for, I understand where you are coming from. I needed `absolute` paths though